# Send a variable to a Jeditable function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jeditable

I'm using Jeditable plugin for editing contacts in my webpage. Problem is that I have to send a contact name through Jeditable function to an php handler.

This is a value i want to send to pro_handler.php

```
$contact = $_GET['contact'];
```

This is an Jeditable function that im using to handle textarea

```
    $(".editable_textarea").editable("inc/pro_handler.php", { 
                        type   : 'textarea',
                        select : true,
                        submit : 'OK',
                        cancel : 'cancel',
                        cssclass : "editable",
                        id   : 'elementid',
                        data : 
                        name : 'newvalue',
                      });
```

So I want to somehow pass a $contact variable to pro_handler.php somehow and I have no idea how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Is the above Javascript is parsed as PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From [the doc](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable): (Mixed) submitdata: Extra parameters when submitting content. Can be either a hash or function returning a hash.

So, you could do the following.

```
$(".editable_textarea").editable("inc/pro_handler.php", { 
    type : 'textarea',
    select: true,
    submit: 'OK',
    cancel: 'cancel',
    cssclass: "editable",
    id: 'elementid',
    name: 'newvalue',
    submitdata: {"contact": "the_value_to_be_sent"}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have another question.  In my callback function
callback : function(value, settings)
when i try to do 
if (value === "someString") 
why it's not working?

Comment: it was some sort of bug. I had to do value.substr(1,3) to cut first character idk why